# How to mount windows folder using docker compose volumes?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

How to mount windows folder using docker compose volumes?

I am trying to set up docker container using `docker-compose`.
My `docker-compose.yml` file looks as follow:

```
php-fpm:
  build: php-fpm
  container_name: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../project:/var/www/dev
```

When i enter to the container like this:

```
docker exec -it php-fpm bash
```

And display content with `ls` command the `/var/www/dev` directory is empty.
Does enyone know the solution for this ?

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e

$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build d988a55
```

I have Windows 10 and docker is installed via Docker ToolBox 1.12.0

@edit
The mounted directory is also empty under Linux enviroment

Comment: May help: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22981

Comment: Are you using Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox? (show your `docker info`). Also, is your docker-compose file under your Users directory? Under Docker Toolbox (virtualbox), only the Users dir is mapped to the host.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by going to: Local Security Policy > Network List Manager Policies and Double-clicked unidentified Networks then change the location type to private and restarted Docker. [Source](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/92)

Comment: This solution may have security risks